# How to pass string into Rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a view that is like this:

```
render  :partial  => 'shared/_address', :locals   => {:address => order.bill_address}
```

With a partial that looks like this:

```
  <b><%= address.name %></b><br/>
  <%= raw address.address_lines('<br/>') %><br/>
  <%= address.city_state_zip %><br/>
```

There are multiple instances of the partial rendered on a page. Instead of having it display address.name, how can I modify my render :partial line so that I am passing on a custom string e.g. "Future Shipping Address" instead of having to use address.name?

So the code would look like below:

```
  <b>STRING GOES HERE</b><br/>
  <%= raw address.address_lines('<br/>') %><br/>
  <%= address.city_state_zip %><br/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
render :partial => 'shared/address', :locals => {:my_string=>"my string", :address => order.bill_address}
```

**in partial**

```
<b><%= my_string %></b><br/>
<%= raw address.address_lines('<br/>') %><br/>
<%= address.city_state_zip %><br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

view:

```
render 'shared/_address', address: order.bill_address, custom_string: 'foobar'
```

partial:

```
<b><%= custom_string %></b>
<%= raw address.address_lines('<br/>') ....
```