# Rails 4 partial pass string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to pass a string to my partial:

Calling my partial this way:

```
render 'translations', locals: { lang: 'en', listing: @listing}
```

in `.../listings/_translations.html.haml` I have:

```
= lang
```

I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `lang' for #<#<Class:0x007fda182ea4b...
```

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081526/how-to-pass-string-into-rails-partial) didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @suslov that did it, good thinking! do you mind posting that as an answer? I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

With a `locals` hash, you either need to explicitly render the partial:

```
render partial: 'translations', locals: {lang: 'en', listing: @listing}
```

Or with the shorthand format you're using, just omit the nested `locals` hash:

```
render 'translations', lang: 'en', listing: @listing
```